# How to customize the URL of Date-based generic views?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-views

Here is my URL pattern:

```
news_info_month_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.published.filter(is_published=True),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
    'month_format': '%m',
}
```

and

```
(r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+).html$', 
    'object_detail', news_info_month_dict, 'news_detail'),
```

But they have an error likes this:

```
object_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category'
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to write your own view in place of the generic `object_detail`, something like this (untested)

```
import datetime

def view_entry(request, category, year, month, day, slug):
    date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, slug=slug, date=date, is_published=True, category=category)
    return render_to_response('news_detail', {'object': entry})
```

Though it may be possible to do it with `object_detail` I don't know - I very rarely use generic views.

Comment: Sorry, function datetime.date does not accept variables. They want the integers.

Answer (score 0):

In your URL regex, everything in `<brackets>` is getting passed to the generic view as a keyword argument.

The problem is that the generic view you're using (`object_detail`) doesn't support all of those arguments (namely, `category`).

[More information about the object_detail generic view and the arguments it accepts.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-date-based-object-detail)

If you need a `category` argument, just wrap the view as Nick suggested above and call that from your URLconf.